# What is the maximum length of a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, memory

I thought this would be an easy google search but nothing came up.

Say I create a loop that continually appends one character at a time to a variable.

At what point will the program crash?

I expect it will take <6 seconds for someone to comment "Why don't you try it and find out?", but trying it wouldn't tell me the answer to the question. Is it implementation-specific? Is it defined anywhere? It doesn't seem to be in the ECMAScript spec.

Are there any known limitations beyond available memory? Does performance degrade with strings holding Mbs or Gbs of text?

For the record, I *did* try running that loop....and it just crashed my browser :( Maybe if I make some adjustments and try again.

Comment: How much memory do you have? :) Operations on a string are defined by their implementation. For example, `length` is O(1) so there is no consequence of it being larger (perhaps a very small upfront allocation cost, but of course, filling that much memory has a cost)

Comment: I think it's pretty unfair to dismiss this question. It's intellectually interesting, at least. Would you prefer to close this rather than than the 4040954590 homework questions? Come on.

Comment: In response to _It doesn't seem to be in the ECMAScript spec_. There is a paragraph on the [ECMAScript 2015 - 6.1.4 The String Type](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type) about this.

Comment: @VaughanHilts - you are correct, it _is_ far more interesting than homework questions. Writing code is about living within limits. Contributing here is about that too - I agree there is nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ECMAScript 2016 (ed. 7) established a maximum length of `2^53 - 1`
>   elements. Previously, no maximum length was specified. In Firefox,
>   strings have a maximum length of `2**30 - 2` (**~1GB**).
>   In versions prior
>   to Firefox 65, the maximum length was `2**28- 1` (~256MB).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length